# Radio button in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, radio-button

I am trying to create an HTML table with textbox, radio buttons and dropdown list. The textbox and dropdown list work. The radio buttons do not. This is because radio buttons have multiple 'input type' lines and they all require different and unique IDs. However, the function is done in a way that 'document.getElementById' is needed. So, if I put the same IDs for all the radio buttons (I know this is wrong), only the first option is selected. If I change the 'document.getElementById' into 'document.getElementsByName', I get  "undefined" in the column when I run it.

Is there any workaround on it?

This is the link for the code -> https://jsfiddle.net/a0zs30Lm/1/

The code is attached below too.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<table class="table table-bordered" align='lhttps://jsfiddle.net/a0zs30Lm/#embedeft' cellspacing=2.5 cellpadding=7.5 id="data_table" border=1>
<tr>
<th>Language Name</th>
<th>Spoken Proficiency</th>
<th>Written Proficiency</th>
<th>Understanding Proficiency</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
<td>
  <input type="radio" name="spoken-list" id="option-1" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="spoken-list" id="option-2" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="spoken-list" id="option-3" value="other"> Other<br><br>
</td>
<td>
    <select name="written-list" id="written-list">
    <option value="Excellent" id="option-1">Excellent</option>
    <option value="Good" id="option-2">Good</option>
    <option value="Poor" id="option-3">Poor</option>
    </select> 
</td>
<td>
    <select name="understand-list" id="understand-list">
    <option value="Excellent" id="option-1">Excellent</option>
    <option value="Good" id="option-2">Good</option>
    <option value="Poor" id="option-3">Poor</option>
    </select> 
</td>
<td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" id="add-button"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

<script>
var myArray = [{"name":"aaa","spoken":"","written":"AA","understand":"AAA"},{"name":"bbb","spoken":"B","written":"BB","understand":"BBB"},{"name":"ccc","spoken":"C","written":"CC","understand":"CCC"}];
var addButton=document.getElementById("add-button"); 

//listen to add button. If clicked, store the entered data and append them in the display
addButton.addEventListener('click', add_row, false);

function add_row(){
 event.preventDefault();
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
 var new_spoken=document.getElementById("spoken-list").value;
 var new_written=document.getElementById("written-list").value;
 var new_understand=document.getElementById("understand-list").value;

 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;

 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML=
 "<tr id= 'row"+table_len+"'>\
    <td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td>\
    <td id='spoken_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_spoken+"</td>\
    <td id='written_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_written+"</td>\
    <td id='understand_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_understand+"</td>\
    <td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> \
        <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> \
        <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'>\
    </td>\
 </tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
}

function edit_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="block";

 var name=document.getElementById("name_row"+no);
 var spoken=document.getElementById("spoken_row"+no);
 var written=document.getElementById("written_row"+no);
 var understand=document.getElementById("understand_row"+no);


 var name_data=name.innerHTML;
 var spoken_data=spoken.innerHTML;
 var written_data=written.innerHTML;
 var understand_data=understand.innerHTML;

 name.innerHTML="<input type='text' id='name_text"+no+"' value='"+name_data+"'>";
 spoken.innerHTML='<select id="spoken-list'+no+'">\
                    <option value="Excellent" id="option-1">Excellent</option>\
                    <option value="Good" id="option-2">Good</option>\
                    <option value="Poor" id="option-3">Poor</option>\
                    </select>' ;

  written.innerHTML='<select id="written-list'+no+'">\
                    <option value="Excellent" id="option-1">Excellent</option>\
                    <option value="Good" id="option-2">Good</option>\
                    <option value="Poor" id="option-3">Poor</option>\
                    </select>' ;

  understand.innerHTML='<select id="understand-list'+no+'">\
                    <option value="Excellent" id="option-1">Excellent</option>\
                    <option value="Good" id="option-2">Good</option>\
                    <option value="Poor" id="option-3">Poor</option>\
                    </select>' ;

document.getElementById("name_text"+no).value = name_data; 
document.getElementById("spoken-list"+no).value = spoken_data;        
document.getElementById("written-list"+no).value = written_data;  
document.getElementById("understand-list"+no).value = understand_data;  
}

function save_row(no)
{
 var name_val=document.getElementById("name_text"+no).value;
 var spoken_val=document.getElementById("spoken-list"+no).value;
 var written_val=document.getElementById("written-list"+no).value;
 var understand_val=document.getElementById("understand-list"+no).value;

 document.getElementById("name_row"+no).innerHTML=name_val;
 document.getElementById("spoken_row"+no).innerHTML=spoken_val;
 document.getElementById("written_row"+no).innerHTML=written_val;
 document.getElementById("understand_row"+no).innerHTML=understand_val;

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+no).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+no).style.display="none";
}

function delete_row(no)
{
 document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="get-text.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could use `var new_spoken = document.querySelector('[name="spoken-list"]:checked').value;` to select the value of the radio. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roLqbtoo/)

Comment: @kakamg0 LOL did you just copy/paste the comment I had posted but accidentally deleted...

Comment: @NewToJS Hahaha Nope, I guess we thought the same

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted my comment. - You can use `document.querySelector("input[name='spoken-list']:checked").‌​value;` For more details about `querySelector()` please read the [**querySelector() Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: How to edit this part to show the radio buttons when I click the 'Edit' button (it's in the "function edit_row(no)" part of the code)?

spoken.innerHTML='<select id="spoken-list'+no+'">\
                    <option value="Excellent" id="option-1">Excellent</option>\
                    <option value="Good" id="option-2">Good</option>\
                    <option value="Poor" id="option-3">Poor</option>\
                    </select>' ;